# Whats the best way to copy files from 2 diferents folders to a new one using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im setting up a program that will check two different folder and copy all the files from the in a third one. The problem for me here is how to copy them without their names?

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.renameSync("/home/oem/git/test/folder1/test1.js", "/home/oem/git/test/folder1/test1CHANGED.js")

console.log("file renamed");

fs.rename("/home/oem/git/test/folder1/test2", "/home/oem/git/test/folder2", function(err){
    if(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("file moved successfully");
    }
});
```

with the code above i can move files that i manually write thei r names, i want to implement it somehow that it will automatically scan the folder and change them to the other one!

Comment: Hey joao, Please offer more information related to the folder structure, file types, the code that you have that you want to add to this feature, and please try to check the community rules for asking a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)

Comment: @Ahm. thank you, im new here so i probably need to learn a lot before going out asking questions =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a Function that could help you to do this

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function copyFiles() {
    const firstFolder = 'firstFolder';
    const secondFolder = 'secondFolder';
    const destinationFolder = 'destinationFolder';
    const firstDir = path.join(__dirname, firstFolder);
    const secondDir = path.join(__dirname, secondFolder);
    const destDir = path.join(__dirname, destinationFolder);
    fs.readdir(firstDir, (err, files) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i += 1) {
            fs.copyFile(firstDir + '/' + files[i], destDir + '/' + files[i], function (err) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
            });
        }

    });
    fs.readdir(secondDir, (err, files) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i += 1) {
            fs.copyFile(secondDir + '/' + files[i], destDir + '/' + files[i], function (err) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
            });
        }

    });
}

copyFiles();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look on [nodes docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_copyfile_src_dest_flags_callback) where it mentions this more detailed

If I may assume that there is two folder `folder1` and `folder2`

`folder1` where there is file `word.txt` and `folder2` is empty

In the script file(assuming also that it lives with the two folders) you can write

```js
const fs = require('fs');

// destination.txt will be created or overwritten by default.
// you can do the renaming here
fs.copyFile('./folder1/word.txt', './folder2/destination.txt', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('word.txt was copied to destination.txt');
});
```

Comment: thank you again, i reformulated my question and got the answers that i was in need. hope you have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to copy file

```
const fs = require('fs');

function copies(fs, files, destination)
{
  for (i=0;i<files.length;i++) {

    // destination file will be created or overwritten by default.
    fs.copyFile(files[i], destionation + '/' + files[i].replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''), (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
      console.log(files[i] +' was copied to ' + destination);
    });
  }
}

var files = ['/path/to/source/files.txt', '/sources/files/files2.txt'];

var destination = '/file/would/copy/to';

copies(fs, files, destination);
```

Comment: thank you for you time, i took all the anwsers here and found the solution that fit best in my case